# Crop a raster by a grid shapefile with different extensions in R

Tags: r, extents, vector-grid, function, clip

I need crop a raster by a grid shapefile to obtain raster files cutted according to grid cells (which are named "PageNumber"). My function is:

> g=shapefile("50x50km_final.shp")
>
> f=raster("declivcerrado.tif")
>
> cell=nrow(g)
>
> i=1
>
> for (i in 1:cell){
>     print(paste("Processando paisagem",i,"de",cell))
>     tmp=subset(g,g$PageNumber==i) 
>     tmp1=crop(f,tmp)
>     writeRaster(tmp1,paste("paisag",i,sep=""),format='HFA',overwrite=T)
>   }

But I got this error:

> Error in .local(x, y, ...) : extents do not overlap

The files extent and projection are:

> extent(g)
>   class       : Extent 
>   xmin        : -654873.4 
>   xmax        : 1381884 
>   ymin        : -1416856 
>   ymax        : 1056824
>
> extent(f)
>   class       : Extent 
>   xmin        : -60.40702 
>   xmax        : -40.48814 
>   ymin        : -24.70977 
>   ymax        : -2.266753
>
> projection(g)
>   [1] "+proj=aea +lat_1=-2 +lat_2=-22 +lat_0=-12 +lon_0=-54 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"
>
> projection(f)
>   [1] "+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +no_defs

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Start with library(rgdal); g <- spTransform(g, projection(f)); to put the vector data into the same projection as the raster.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I've tryied the transformation and it really works. But would be more interesting for me the opposite, put the raster into the same projection as vector. Is it possible? How?

Comment: projectRaster, but this is of course an expensive and destructive resampling process with many complicatedoptions for optimization. ( Try leaflet::addRaster for an interactive view, and just for fun! (though only in Mercator project atm).